# Is it posible to define Process-Definition Constant?

Tags: jbpm

I want to know if there is a way to define constants in a process definition in design time (not process instance). I'm implementing a custom frontend application that lists all process definitions that exist in a container.  And I need a way to know the URL of the associated form that launches the page in the frontend, so I can capture all the required information in this custom form and then create the process instance.  I want to get this information from a constant defined in the process definition.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Within the [offical JBPM docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/latest/jbpm-docs/html_single/#proc-define-global-variables_business-processes) you can find information about 'global variables'.
Globals are variables that are shared for all process instances of the same process definition.

To use them you need to define it within the Business Central first. Therfore simply add them in the properties window of your business process model:
[image]

You can read the global variable (e.g. on your script task) via: `kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().getGlobal(name);` or by simply access it directly by name like with all local variables: `myglobal;`

To set the initial value on design time you can use the project settings within Business Central:
[image]

You can change it while runtime via: `kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal(name, value);`

Comment: @jvacaq does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, but i'm still not able to use a global variable in my DLR. When printing it I get null when running my test scenario. Maybe I'm missing something with the KIE Session? `kcontext.getKieRuntime().getGlobals().getGlobalKeys()` returns an empty list.

Thank you